# phpmyadmin symlinks error after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, mysql

After the upgrade of my ubuntu server to 13.04 my phpmyadmin is no longer reachable. the browser reports 500 (internal server error) and in the error.log it says:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.') in
>                    /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 370

Any other php software works fine on the machine and so does mysql itself. Phpmyadmin is installed correctly and worked fine before the dist-upgrade. i also did `sudo aptitude reinstall phpmyadmin` but that did not help.

the version number of phpmyadmin is 4:3.5.8.1-1

any ideas, what could be wrong here?

/edit: by now i found out, that the symlinks here do not seem to work:

```
mcnesium@fluse:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/php-gettext$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Apr 25 03:38 gettext.inc -> ../../../php/php-gettext/gettext.inc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Apr 25 03:38 gettext.php -> ../../../php/php-gettext/gettext.php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Apr 25 03:38 streams.php -> ../../../php/php-gettext/streams.php
```

i backed up the folder `php-gettext` and cp -r'd the symlinked one over, now it works. so this actually seems to be a symlink-problem.

this is the beginning of my `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

so it is supposed to follow symlinks right away. before the ubuntu upgrade everything worked fine. so whats the matter with the symlinks?

Comment: Check the permissions under `/usr/share/php/php-gettext`. Are you using SELinux/AppArmor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me the following solution solved the problem:

In my website conf file, I have the following section:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off
    php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
    php_value include_path .
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
    php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/
</IfModule>
```

The only change I've made since Ubuntu 13.04 install is include /usr/share/php/php-gettext/ in the open_basedir, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 23):

For others:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

might be the answer (especially with php7 as it seems that this is not included by default, maybe because it is a pear extension).

Comment: I got the error after performing a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. It worked after upgrading 15.10 to 16.04, but I had to do a fresh install due to other problems. Explicitly installing the `php-gettext` package (and adding `Require all granted` to `phpmyadmin.conf`) made it work again.

Comment: this is the actual answer!

Comment: Thanks for that; I didn't think of that; this and `php-mbstring` were required to get phpmyadmin to work right for me with php7

Comment: It's odd, because php-gettext is a dependency of the phpmyadmin package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/phpmyadmin so I'm not sure why it's not already there.

Comment: Install LAMP first, then phpmyadmin, maybe that is part of the problem

Answer (score 5):

If your `open_basedir` contains `/usr/share/php/php-gettext/` already (as in my case) and you can't get it to work with the previous answers then do:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/php-gettext/*
```

*removes the symbolic links*

```
sudo ln /usr/share/php/php-gettext/* /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/php-gettext
```

*creates hard links*

This makes phpmyadmin work again. Why it broke in 13.04 and the symbolic links aren't followed while the apache.conf says they should, remains a mystery to me.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. The open_basedir line already contained the php-gettext directory so reinstalling those links was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable (prefix with `#`) the `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` since I'm using a custom vhost file for phpmyadmin to serve it on a subdomain. With the additional `Alias` it didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If phpMyAdmin runs on an Nginx server, the `php.ini` additionally needs to add the path `/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext`to the `open_basedir` key.